# Linear Transformations of Functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

$\textbf{Problem}$

Define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = mx + b$.

$\textbf{a.}$ Show that $f$ is a linear transformation when $b = 0$.

$\textbf{b.}$ Find a property of linear transformation that is violated when $b \ne 0$

$\textbf{c.}$ Why is $f$ called a linear function?

Comment: In part **b.** do you mean "when $b\ne 0$"?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Solution}$

$\textbf{a.)}$ Given:

$\textbf{Transformation}$:
$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$\textbf{Function}$

$f(x) = mx + b$

Assumptions:
$b = 0$.
$x,y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}$.
$c$ and $d$ are scalars.

Statements:
$f(x) = mx$
$f(y) = my$

\begin{align} f(x) + f(y) &= mx + my \\&= m(x + y) \\&= f(x + y) \end{align}

\begin{align} c \dot\ f(x) &= c(mx) \\&= m(cx) \\&=f(cx)\end{align}
\begin{align} d \dot\ f(y) &= d(my) \\&= m(dx) \\&=f(dy) \end{align}

Conclusion:
$f$ is linear.

$\textbf{b.)}$

Assume $b \ne 0$

Then

$f(x) = mx + b$

$f(y) = my + b$
\begin{align*}f(x) + f(y) &= mx + b + my + b \\&=mx + my + 2b \\&=m(x + y) + 2b \\&=f(x + y) + 2b \textbf{ False} \end{align*}

Property $T(\textbf{x + y}) = T(\textbf{x}) + T(\textbf{y})$ of the definition of linear transformation is violated.

$\textbf{c.}$

$f$ is a linear function because it is a polynomial of one degree, has the form $f(x) = ax + b$ where $a, b$ are constants, and its graph is a non-vertical line.

Comment: In part **a.)** don't you mean $b=0$ rather than $b\ne0$? In part **b.)** you probably should explain what you mean by "Property $(i)$ of the definition" since different books can use different definitions.

Comment: Fixed.$\phantom{ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ}$

Comment: It is now a good answer! +1